# Why is Num Lock disabled by default in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Why did anyone ever it would be a good idea to disable Num Lock on Linux at startup? It annoys the heck outta me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most laptops need numlock disabled to be able to type normally - it would be a very bad idea indeed to indiscriminately enable numlock. Nik's link tells you how to change this, but you asked why and that's why.

Comment: I have a laptop and I don't have this problem. I've used Windows for as long as I can remember with the NumLock enabled by default.

Comment: Not all laptops are the same - but a lot have (had?) a 'numpad' in the middle of the keyboard, that's active if numlock is on, so you cannot type normally with it on.

Comment: It's really a bad idea to allow OS to control this setting. It has to be controlled from the bios, and there must be **additional** option, like in troubleshooting section *"Force disable numlock on startup (For buggy laptops)"*. Other way - dont TOUCH it, please, or you wreck it. I really gave up, finding how to tweak it. And now I just want to set a pistol to head of person, who wrote that malicious code and force him to uncode this part back!! (joking, but it was really awful idea)

Answer (score 6):

<sub>You seem quite frustrated on this</sub>,
Maybe this [Ubuntu page for NumLock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock) will help.

Comment: +1 for the advice, but I asked why it is disabled by default so I'll have to mark Bobby's answer as correct.

Comment: The page is totally outdated as per today, ubuntu does not contain `System Settings > Keyboard Layout > Options > Miscellaneous compatibility options` page anymore..

Answer (score 0):

At least in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, this behavior might be because of a bug:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/509029/numlock-light-turns-off-when-you-switch-language-with-super-space